# Existing entity cannot be updated with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

My Spring Boot app has the following classes:

> **Board** (JPA entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "board")
public class Board {
  public static final int IN_PROGRESS = 1;
  public static final int AFK         = 2;
  public static final int COMPLETED   = 3;

  @Column(name = "id")
  @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
  private int status = IN_PROGRESS;
}
```

> **BoardRepository** (JPA repository)

```
public interface BoardRepository extends JpaRepository<Board, Long> {}
```

> **CommonBoardService** (base service)

```
public interface CommonBoardService {
  Board save(Board board);
  Board update(Board board, int status);
}
```

> **CommonBoardServiceImpl** (base service implementation)

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CommonBoardServiceImpl implements CommonBoardService {
  @Autowired
  private BoardRepository boardRepository;

  public Board save(final Board board) {
    return boardRepository.save(board);
  }

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public Board update(final Board board, final int status) {
    board.setStatus(status);

    return save(board);
  }
}
```

> **BoardService** (specific service interface)

```
public interface BoardService {
  Board startBoard();
  void synchronizeBoardState(Board board);
}
```

> **BoardServiceImpl** (specific service implementation)

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BoardServiceImpl implements BoardService {
  @Autowired
  private CommonBoardService commonBoardService;

  public Board startBoard() { return new Board(); }

  public void synchronizeBoardState(final Board board) {
    if (board != null && inProgress(board)) {
      if (!canPlayWithCurrentBoard(board)) {
        commonBoardService.update(board, Board.AFK);
      }
      else {
        commonBoardService.update(board, Board.COMPLETED);
      }
    }
  }

  private boolean canPlayWithCurrentBoard(final Board board) {
    return !inProgress(board);
  }

  private boolean inProgress(final Board board) {
    return board != null && board.getStatus() == Board.IN_PROGRESS;
  }
}
```

> **BoardServiceTest** (unit test)

```
1.  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
2.  @Transactional
3.  public class BoardServiceTest {
4.    @Autowired
5.    private BoardRepository boardRepository;
6.
7.    @Autowired
8.    private BoardService       boardService;
9.    @Autowired
10.   private CommonBoardService commonBoardService;
11.
12.   @Test
13.   public void testSynchronizeBoardStatus() {
14.     Board board = boardService.startBoard();
15.
16.     board = commonBoardService.save(board);
17.
18.     assertEquals(1, boardRepository.count());
19.
20.     boardService.synchronizeBoardState(board);
21.
22.     assertEquals(1, boardRepository.count());
23.   }
24. }
```

This test fails on line 22 with the error `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected :1 Actual:2`. Hibernate SQL logs reveal an `INSERT` being fired on line 20 instead of an `UPDATE`. Since I am using the same `Board` object throughout the test, I expect line 20 to fire an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to get the expected behaviour (`UPDATE` on line 20)?

Comment: Which database is your TestDataSourceConfiguration.class pointing to? Does it have the board entity you want to update?

Comment: What are `boardService` and `commonBoardService` in `BoardServiceTest`?  What do `boardService.startBoard(admin)` and `commonBoardService.save(board)` look like? Presumably, the first is creating a new `board` and the second saving it? Also, what does the code for the `Board` and `User` classes look like? It may be better if you can create a small sample that demonstrates the problem as there is quite a lot of code to cover.

Comment: @koder23, thanks for response. I am using postgres. Yea, it should has as `Board board = boardService.startBoard(admin);` - create the new board, and the ID of the entity is equals to 1.

Comment: Can you post the complete code to test it out? There are still many parts missing that make it difficult to reproduce the problem. May be post a sample app on Github?

Comment: @manish, you are right, `boardService.startBoard(admin)` - create new board, for the user. As you can see, the `boardService.synchronizeBoardState(board, admin)` has different checks. So, I want to trigger the case when we are going inside the  `if (!canPlayWithCurrentBoard(board))` code block. To achieve that I need update the `board` entity to met those condition. That is why I use  the `commonBoardService.save(board)` in the test.

Comment: @manish, Ok, I will add the rest of the code. If I'll miss some component, please tell me.

Comment: @manish, I have updated the question

Comment: @I.Domshchikov, I have simplified your code as it was overly long. A [sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/37698026) is also available on Github. The problem you are facing is reproducible in the sample app.

Comment: @manish, thanks appreciate that.

Comment: Your title includes Spring Boot but I don't see anything Spring Boot related in your setup or testcase...

Comment: @I.Domshchikov, can you try my sample application linked in my answer below and check after remove `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`?

Comment: @manish. I have looked into the provided sample and have a comment. The `boardService.startBoard()` method besides creating new entity, also should save it into db. In my impl, it works that way.

Comment: @manish. I couldn't remove the `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` as it would change my business logic. If everything would be run in the same transaction, than in case of any exception all transaction will be rollback.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this line: `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. Lets see what happens when the test case is executed.

- Because `BoardServiceTest` is annotated with `@Transactional` a new transaction is started when `BoardServiceTest.testSynchronizeBoardStatus` starts executing.
- Line 14 creates a new `Board` instance.
- Line 16 attempts to save the `Board` instance created on line 14 and triggers a database `INSERT`.
- Line 20 indirectly invokes `CommonBoardServiceImpl.update` which is annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. This suspends the ongoing transaction (see the [JavaDocs for Propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW)), which has neither been committed nor been rolled back so far.
- `CommonBoardServiceImpl.update` in turn attempts to save the `Board` instance passed to it.
- The given instance is not recognized as an existing instance because the transaction that saved it to the database is currently in suspended state. Hence, it is assumed to be a new instance and results in a second `INSERT`.
- Line 20 now finishes, which commits the inner transaction started for `CommonBoardServiceImpl.update`. The outer transaction resumes.
- Line 22 finds a dirty session and flushes it before firing a `SELECT` query. This means there are now two instances in the database, hence the test failure.

Removing `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` ensures that the entire test is executed within the same transaction and hence passes.